# Close current browser tab and focus on a browser tab of a specific url - javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, browser-tab

I am building an application. In which I want close current browser tab and I want to focus on a tab that's url I'll pass. If browser contains a tab with that url then that tab should be focused and if browser is not contains a tab with that url then a new window should be opened.
For closing current tab it's working `window.close()` but what should I do for focus on a tab.

Comment: You don't really control that stuff, the user does. It's up to the user how windows and tabs are opened etc.

Comment: You could only close current tab. You can't control which tab is brought to front after that.

Comment: Is there no way to focus on a tab?? @Leo

Comment: You don't even know how many tabs are opened in the browser. That's the user's privacy, browsers won't let you know.

Comment: Can I focus on previous tab @Leo

Comment: That depends on the browser vendors, or the user's settings. The only way a third party can do so, I guess is a browser extension - such as CRX for Chrome, XPI for Firefox.

Comment: Thank You But I don't want it from third party.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Getting a list of tabs of the current window.
chrome.windows.getLastFocused(
 // Without this, window.tabs is not populated.
 {populate: true},
 function (window)
 {
  var foundSelected = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < window.tabs.length; i++)
  {
   // Finding the selected tab.
   if (window.tabs[i].active)
   {
    foundSelected = true;
   }
   // Finding the next tab.
   else if (foundSelected)
   {
    // Selecting the next tab.
    chrome.tabs.update(window.tabs[i].id, {active: true});
    return;
   }
  }
 });
```